# Plotting my point set gives me lines between points that are far apart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a hand drawn curve as an image . I created the image from paint.Now my task is to fit that curve to a polynomial.I need to have the coordinates of all the points from that curve.After that i need to fit using those points .

For getting the coordinates i tried to traverse through the image and got all the coordinates such that the pixel value at that coordinate is not 255.

```
OP=[]

for i in range(gray_image.shape[0]):
  for j in range(gray_image.shape[1]):
    if gray_image[i,j]!=255:
      OP.append(tuple([j,i]))
```

But when i am trying to fit i am getting a dense region instead of smooth curve

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

You haven't tried to fit a curve yet. You have tried to plot your point set.

That plot you're getting happens because you ***should*** have used a `scatter` plot, not a line plot.

Your points have no order. They need no order.

Fitting a polynomial is then a least squares problem on this ***set*** of points.

Use `np.nonzero()` to ***quickly*** gather all the coordinates of the nonzero elements in your mask. Don't use that loop there.

Comment: Thanks and it worked out good..if the drawn curve is so thick then how to  remove some points so that i can get a smooth curve?

Comment: least squares fitting uses all the points, no matter how "thick" the line is. giving fewer points has no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You got to sort your points by x coordinate. The way you gather your points, you are getting pairs of points that have the same y value together. When you plot, it goes back and forth, creating the effect you are seeing.

As mentioned in the comment, the problem is only when plotting. The fit should be ok regardless of the order of the points.

Comment: for fitting, this is not an issue. it's simply a set of points.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz You are correct. It's when he plots.